# Resizing image file rotate it horizontally android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation, imageview

Hey I have an app that choose an image from the gallery , resizing it and uploading it to ftp server , but I have notice that in some photo's the app flips the image horizontally and upload it backwards, I can't figure out why it is happening (It only happened on some photos and on others not, usually happened on photos taken from my camera)

Here is the code for the resize part:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK&&data!=null) {


        selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        showUri = data.getData();
        imagePath = RealPathUtil.getPath(this,data.getData());
        loadedImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //loadedImage.setImageURI(data.getData());
            Glide.with(this).load(data.getData())
                    .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upload_image1));

            ImageView m =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.remove_image);
            m.setFocusable(true);
            m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            File file = new File(RealPathUtil.getPath(this,data.getData()));

            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file);

            ImageResizer(bitmap);


        }

    }
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=200;

        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        Bitmap bit1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        //Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        //matrix.postRotate(45);
      //  Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bit1 , 0, 0, bit1 .getWidth(), bit1 .getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bit1;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

private void ImageResizer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Pic");
    if(!myDir.exists()) myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "resized.png";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()){
        file.delete();
        Log.d("exist","replace");
        SaveResized(file, bitmap);
    } else {
        SaveResized(file, bitmap);
        Log.d("saved","now");

    }
    selectedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
    imagePath = RealPathUtil.getPath(this,selectedImageURI);
}

private void SaveResized(File file, Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

can someone help me and tell me why is it happening?

Comment: You are neglecting the orientation parameter in the Exif header of the original jpg files. And you create new jpg files without Exif information.